# ExecuteReader? Connection property has not been initialized

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to do a login form, but when i try to login, I get an exception.

I'm using a separate file called `conexaoDB.cs` to create the connection with all info about the DB

Outside the button:

```
ConexaoDB conexao = new ConexaoDB();
```

Inside the button:

```
try
{
    conexao.conn();

    string sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE users_login = @login AND users_pass = @senha";

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@login", login);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@senha", senha);

    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Popup next window = " + login + " // " + senha);
        tryLogin = true;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Login ou senha inválidos.");
        tryLogin = false;
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Catch: " + ex.Message);
}
```

This is only to learn SQL connection, is not a real database with real logins and passwords

Comment: Yikes, this a looks a lot like the database is storing passwords in plain text. That is **NOT OKAY.**

Comment: `command = new SqlCommand(sql, conexao);`

Comment: @LarsTech's got it right: You don't associate your SqlCommand with any connection. What is conexao.conn(); supposed to do? Should it return a connection? Does initialize some nasty global connection?. Also AddWithValue is considered bad practice by some.

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/addwithvalue

Comment: Password handling is one of those things that's too important to do wrong _even on learning/practice/proof-of-concept projects_.

Comment: I even know how to connect on database, im going by parts

Comment: We don't know what `ConexaoDB` is, but if it has an SqlConnection property, you need to use it for your SqlCommand like `command = new SqlCommand(sql, conexao.Connection);` or something like that.  If you are learning, then creating a `ConexaoDB` class (assuming it's handling SqlConnection stuff) is probably making things harder.  Don't leave your connections open and put your disposable objects in a using-block.

Comment: @LarsTech `conexaoDB` is a separate class to create the connection with database. I've tried to use the `command = new SqlCommand(sql, conexao.conn);`, but it returns a "cannot convert from 'method group' to 'SqlConnection'.

Comment: Honestly, don't use `ConexaoDB`.  Use the SqlConnection class directly.  I'm guessing you are keeping your connection open, which you shouldn't do.  Use this example as a guide: [SqlConnection Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0)

Comment: ConexaoDB can makes as many valid or invalid connections as it wants, you are not trying to use one in your SqlCommand. Please show the code of ConexaoDB if you want any further help.

Comment: `command = new SqlCommand(sql, conexao.conn());` But again: you probably need a `using` block here as well, because you really are better off creating a brand new connection object for every query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop the ConexaoDB stuff, especially if you are trying to keep one connection open at all time. That is bad practice, built-in connection pooling will work much better.

This should work:

```cs
try
{
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE users_login = @login AND users_pass = @senha";

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection)
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@login", login);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@senha", senha);

            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                tryLogin = reader.HasRows;
                if (tryLogin)
                {
                    // Extremely bad practice to show password in a messagebox, but I assume it's for test 
                    MessageBox.Show("Popup next window = " + login + " // " + senha);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Login ou senha inválidos.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (SqlException ex) // Don't catch too broad an exception, be specific
{
    MessageBox.Show("Catch: " + ex.Message);
}
```

The usings are taking care of closing and disposing and the SqlConnection goes back to the connection pool and will be reused.

**Important**:
You should not store passwords as clear text in the database. Best practice is to generate a hash, with a salt and store the hashed value in the database. When authenticating the user you compute the hash again on the password input by the user and compare the two hashes. This assures that your password table is useless to an attacker if it gets stolen.

Comment: It worked, but I've only changed the `tryLogin = reader.HasRows();` to `tryLogin = reader.HasRows;`

Comment: And I add `connection.Open();` inside the first using-block and after the secont using-block

Comment: Nice, I changed it the answer. Good finds ;-)